# How to export map in draft mode?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, cartography, arcgis-10.2

ArcMap 10.2.

I want to export map in draft mode. Without layers. Only few rectangles displaying main part of map, legend, scale bars, north arrows, margins and guide lines.

E.g. something like this:

[image]

Is it possible? I've tried to export by Export Map but I got normal map.

Answer (score 1):

Within the layout view, make sure your layout elements have been converted to graphics, turn all your layers off, then select File menu>Export Map.

Alternatively, if you don't want to convert your legend to a graphic you could only turn off any WMS basemap layers, then zoom way out and pan to a part of the Earth where your data is not showing, then select File menu>Export Map.

Comment: I want to export exactly the same view as you can see on my screenshot. With grey rectangles and guide lines.

Comment: If you want the guidelines and everything you can see on screen could you not just do as you have done for the question - take a screenshot and use that?